# Simple Swift Cocoa app with WebKit: Upload picture doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I decided to make my own FB chat app that simply shows https://messenger.com on a `WebView` after trying other 'freemium' apps.

My `ViewController.swift` has just a few lines of code that loads URL on the web view

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://messenger.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request);
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Besides adding `NSAppTransportSecurity` key to info.plist to unblock HTTP traffic via HTTPS connection, I have not done any other settings.

#### Question

Please take a look at this image first.

[image: Screenshot of testing app]

Everything looks fine & working except two things.

1. Uploading image does not work - I labeled as 1 in the picture.

   - normally (as in other released apps or from web browsers) if you click that icon, it shows an explorer to upload a picture like below.
     [image: example of browser upload image]
   - My app completely ignores user's click on that icon so I cannot upload any pictures to the chat. **Interestingly, if I drag and drops the picture to the `webview`, it uploads fine.**
2. Shared picture does not show up - I labeled as 2 in the picture.

   - again, from other browsers or released apps, it shows the pictures that I shared with participants like below. (of course I censored the pictures)
     [image: example of browser showing shared pics]
   - my app tries to load the pics, but does not display them. I can see it trying to load because I see circular progress indicator while loading.

#### Why?

1. I suspect that there might be a way to listen to the JavaScript that's triggered within the `WebView` and link to a file explorer or something like that?
2. This I have no idea. I'm logged into Messenger (basically Facebook), so I think `session` is not a problem here. Maybe some jQuery loading issue??

What should I do to solve these issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. There is indeed a delegate method to open a new panel called `runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener`, [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:).

In the delegate method, just create a new NSOpenPanel like this:

```
func webView(sender: WebView!, runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener resultListener: WebOpenPanelResultListener!, allowMultipleFiles: Bool) {
    let openDialog = NSOpenPanel()
    if (openDialog.runModal() == NSOKButton) {
        let fileName: String = (openDialog.URL?.path)!
        resultListener.chooseFilename(fileName) // Use chooseFilenames for multiple files
    }
}
```

2. I just tried to create a WebView from Messagers App and images are loading well.
   You should try to enable WebView options like "Autoload Images" or "Enable Animated Images" from interface builder (or by code).

Comment: first one didn't work. I put that in AppDelegate, but it doesn't reach there (checked with debugger..). I don't know the reason for that :(
Second one, everything is checked correctly and I don't know why mine doesn't work and yours do haha.. strange..

Comment: If the delegate method isn't called, it's because you have to tell your WebView which file is the delegate.

You can do it from your interface builder -> select your webview -> go to the right tab called "Show the connections inspector" (icon is an arrow) and then just drag `UIDelegate` to your delegate object.

If my explications aren't clear, [link]https://thoughtfulcode.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/os-x-10-7-lion-2011-11-23-12-00-15.png[/link]

Comment: Sorry here is the link : https://thoughtfulcode.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/os-x-10-7-lion-2011-11-23-12-00-15.png

(it's an old version but xcode 7 is the same)

Comment: omg it worked! I watched [this tutorial](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/uiwebview-and-uiwebviewdelegate/), too. with help of you and the tutorial, I was able to attach file :)

Comment: Still having problem with loading pictures on the right side.. though

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) About loading images maybe try to inspect javascript/http request issues by adding `yourWebView.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")` to see why these images aren't loading. (right click and inspect element like in a regular browser).

Comment: Nov I opened up a new thread after testing with Inspect Element.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879191/cocoa-webview-useragent-webkit-legacy-issue . Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me and what is nice here is that you make the download of image asynchronous. You can find more about this concept here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1 and: http://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2

**Edited**

**I.** You have to create new Class or a new iOS Swift File named **ImageLoader** with this content:

```
class ImageLoader {

var cache = NSCache()

class var sharedLoader : ImageLoader {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in
        var data: NSData? = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData

        if let goodData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: goodData)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            })
            return
        }

        var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                return
            }

            if data != nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: urlString)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                })
                return
            }

        })
        downloadTask.resume()
    })

}
```

}

**II.** In your actual viewController you call the method 'imageForUrl' from ImageLoaded following this lines of code:

```
ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/43/Apple_Swift_Logo.png", completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
        self.myImage.image = image!
    })
```

I took the code from this link: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/does-anyone-know-how-to-show-an-image-from-url-with-swift

**Edited for image loaded on webview**

Here is the code. It works perfect for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/12144725_10204647881668565_4367944825116750386_n.jpg?oh=5ecdae91f5258ffe0e0355e176f8eb8a&oe=56B007CA")!))
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) , but do I put this in delegate? or have to explicitly call it?

Comment: I will edit my answer for better understanding because it's too much to say for a comment :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm really a newbie to Swift Coding.. :'(

Comment: No problem, all of us have to learn more and more :) Please let me know if this works for you. On url path: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/43/Apple_Swift_Logo.png" you have to use your url, this is just an example.

Comment: Hmm I'm afraid that you have misunderstood the question. I do not have any image view or anything to load image from URL. I just have a webview, and the website itself has all the places to load the image, and I do not have control to fix them or anything. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: I edited the answer again and it works perfect. Good luck :)