# Cocoa webview UserAgent "webkit-legacy" issue

Tags: css, swift, macos, cocoa, webkit

> I solved this. Look at the selected answer below!

I've been fighting to find what causes the WebView of OSX Cocoa application to act differently from Safari. It turns out that the user-agent is different (sort of obvious?) and the website I'm visiting does not know how to handle that.

Surprisingly, it's https://messenger.com (facebook chat).

The problem is that it doesn't display the picture on the screen. It does load, but it doesn't actually display. Take a look at this..

[image: Screenshot of testing app]

If you look at the area that I numbered as '2' you just see empty space. I didn't censor that out. It's just empty.

So here's my original question link: [Simple Swift Cocoa app with WebKit: Upload picture doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642521/simple-swift-cocoa-app-with-webkit-upload-picture-doesnt-work)

I solved the first issue (thanks to the answers :D), but second issue persists.

> 2. Shared picture does not show up - I labeled as 2 in the picture.
>
>    - again, from other browsers or released apps, it shows the pictures that I shared with participants like below. (of course I censored the pictures)
>        [image: example of browser showing shared pics]

To debug this, I opened the Inspect Element and I found this out.

```
<body class=" webkit-legacy webkit mac x1 body_textalign Locale_en_US _z4_" dir="ltr">
```

When I did load the exact same page from Safari, I'd see this:

```
<body class="safari webkit mac x1 body_textalign Locale_en_US _z4_" dir="ltr">
```

So I decided to replace that line from WebView of my app, and viola! it works! so...

### TLDR: How do I make this work every time I load the view?

I tried to find some methods to set up my user agent to Safari, but I can't get this to work. Any suggestion please?

Comment: hmm.. my problem might not even be that.. When I change that line from Safari (from safari webkit... to webkit-legacy webkit...), it works perfectly fine.. ahhhhh.... world of css... -_-

Comment: Are you using an UIWebView or a WKWebView?

Comment: I am using UIWebView

Comment: Are all files, including the image, downloaded via https, or are some simple http? If the latter, have you correctly configured App Transport Security?

Comment: Do you have any errors showing up in the app logs?

Comment: Oops, sorry, though it was an iOS app, not sure App Transport Security applies to OS X.

Comment: No there's no error. And yes I configured it correctly so they are showing correctly if I change the class names. So it's correctly loaded but just not showing.

Comment: It does apply so I configured it correctly :)

Comment: It might just be an issue in their browser detection and CSS. You may want to use the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method of the UIWebView delegate, and then `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to execute some Javascript to fix the `class` on the `body`?

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to try WKWebView (not sure it's available on OS X), which uses a different WebKit version which will probably be detected differently.

Comment: @jcaron hey! I did what you suggested, and it worked! if you put your answer in the actual answer, I can choose yours! :) otherwise, I'll answer myself about how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here's the answer.

I added this function in the `ViewController` class.

```
func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.className = 'safari webkit mac x1 Locale_en_US _z4_';")
}
```

Pretty simple, but it's working perfectly fine.

I still have some problems with the app itself (e.g. Download image button doesn't trigger file explorer dialog), but basic functions like

- send/receive messages
- view shared pictures

work just fine.

I'm planning on working on this for

- download image
- notification

If you are interested in helping me out, please comment!

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created simple sample application and fixed this issue. I've provided same user agent, as in Safari. After that, Shared Photos work as expected.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.webView.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7";
    self.webView.mainFrameURL = @"https://messenger.com";
}
```

After that, I compare user agents:

Original WebView user agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)`

Safari user agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7`

So, looks like I need to change only last part of User Agent. Like that:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.webView.applicationNameForUserAgent = @"Safari/601.2.7";
    self.webView.mainFrameURL = @"https://messenger.com";
}
```

With this code, Shared Photos also works. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with other `applicationNameForUserAgent` values I've tried.

Comment: Hmm I tried this and it didn't really do anything. I finally solved it by just editing the `document.body.className` to what I found to be working. Thank you for the insight tho!